# UITableView Footer Resets on Scrolling

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview, footer

I have a simple `UITableView` setup and have a footer view which has just a `UIActivityIndicatorView` in it.

In `viewDidLoad` I call:

```
[_tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"FetchingResultsFooterView" bundle:nil] forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier:@"TableViewFooterFetchingResultsView"];
```

Then I add the tableview methods for my footer:

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [self tableViewFooterHeight];
}

-(CGFloat)tableViewFooterHeight
{
    return 88;
}

-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    static NSString *headerReuseIdentifier = @"TableViewFooterFetchingResultsView";

    APFetchingResultsFooter *footer = [tableView dequeueReusableHeaderFooterViewWithIdentifier:headerReuseIdentifier];
    [footer setTag:kTableViewFooterTag];

    //Centre my activity indicator on screen
    CGFloat aiInset = ((_tableViewContainer.frame.size.width /2) - (footer.activityIndicator.frame.size.width /2));
    CGFloat aiOffset = _tableViewContainer.contentOffset.x + aiInset;
    [footer.activityIndicator setFrame:CGRectMake(aiOffset, ([self tableViewFooterHeight] /2) - (footer.activityIndicator.frame.size.height /2), footer.activityIndicator.frame.size.width, footer.activityIndicator.frame.size.height)];

    return footer;
}
```

This displays my footer more or less as expected, it sits there with my activity indicator.

In case it confuses you, because I have a very wide 'UITableView' inside a 'UIScrollView' I simply centre my activity indicator on screen, rather than the centre of the tableview by offsetting it.

Which leads to this code which just updates the position of the activity indicator as I scroll, so it stays centred (allowing the tableview wider than the screen to use the footer).

```
-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    //Synchronise scrolling
    if (scrollView == _headerView) [_tableViewContainer setContentOffset:_headerView.contentOffset];
    else if (scrollView == _tableViewContainer) [_headerView setContentOffset:_tableViewContainer.contentOffset];

    //because the tableview can be wider than the screen, we adjust the footer contents to be centered as we scroll
    if (scrollView == _tableViewContainer)
    {
        APFetchingResultsFooter *footer = (APFetchingResultsFooter *)[_tableView viewWithTag:kTableViewFooterTag];

        CGFloat aiInset = ((_tableViewContainer.frame.size.width /2) - (footer.activityIndicator.frame.size.width /2));
        CGFloat aiOffset = _tableViewContainer.contentOffset.x + aiInset;
        [footer.activityIndicator setFrame:CGRectMake(aiOffset, ([self tableViewFooterHeight] /2) - (footer.activityIndicator.frame.size.height /2), footer.activityIndicator.frame.size.width, footer.activityIndicator.frame.size.height)];
    }
}
```

So, that is all pretty simple. Now my problem:

As I scroll vertically, when the footer is offscreen and then brought back on-screen, the footer is reset. So the activity indicator is not centred.

I have tried placing the frame update code in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` which kind of works, but as you scroll the footer on-screen, there is a delay and you see the indicator jump from its default frame to its new centred one.

How do I prevent this, so that as it is scrolled on screen (or as the footer is created), have the indicator view updated with a new frame before any jumping can be seen?

Have I just taken the wrong approach?

Comment: Are you using auto layout in your footer view? If so, you shouldn't be setting frames, you should center it by modifying its constraints.

Comment: I am not using auto layout, just updating its frame property.

Comment: Did you you turn it off explicitly, or did you just not add any constraints (the system adds them for you if you don't add your own)?

Comment: I haven't turned them off explicitly, no. Is it possible to do this just for the xib then? I use constraints quite widely across other parts of my application.

Comment: Yes, I think you can turn it off for a single xib file.

Comment: Unfortunately this hasn't made any difference... Thanks for the suggestion though.